Add auto-generated `UpdatedAt field` as sort key to auto-generated GSI in a relationship table

Is this achievable using Amplify Gen2's data schema?
Tried to add sort key in data schema but seems not achievable. Also tried to add sort key in resources.ts generated by amplify, but unfortunately I'm not really experienced with CF, so didn't find where I could add the sort key?

Please copy-paste the code into the question as text and remove the image.
